# Spring batch : call beforeProcess on ItemProcessListener only once

Tags: spring, spring-batch

What I am trying to achive is - I want to call a method **only once** before executing the ItemProcessor.process method.

If I use the ItemProcessListener.beforeProcess , it is called for every item that is read in ItemReader.

Any idea, how to achive this ? Any other alternative to ItemProcessListener ?

Answer (score 1):

Your best choice to be sure method is called once is to use a `StepExecutionListener` and bind this listener to step where you use your ItemProcessor.
Else, if you need to call just before `ItemProcessor.process()` add a `ItemProcessListener` and manage a flag in `StepExecutionContext`: if this flag is not setted (`false`) or absent call the method and set flag to `true` else do nothing.
But if you can be more precise about your use-case a better solution can be found.
Hope can help!